# How do I configure options in DI and use them globally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the package AspnetCore.HtmlSanitizer. [Here](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)

I am trying to register the service with the default options and only remove certain tags and attributes. For example, I am OK with all the default attributes except "href" how do I remove it globally through startup.cs?

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.Configure<HtmlSanitizerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowedTags.Remove("a");
            options.AllowedAttributes.Remove("href");
        });


        // Services
        services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSanitizer, HtmlSanitizer>();
```

This is not removing the "a" and "href" from the list of attributes and tags.

I simply want to configure it in startup.cs and use the same options globally across my application.

Can someone please help

Comment: I see that HtmlSanitizer has two overloaded ctor:
public HtmlSanitizer()
public HtmlSanitizer(HtmlSanitizerOptions options)

Are you sure, it is calling the one with HtmlSanitizerOptions?

Comment: How do you get the HtmlSanitizer instance inside your code?

Comment: through dependency injection

Answer (score 2):

Construct the options object in DI and send it with the HtmlSanitizer object.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSantitizer, HtmlSanitizer>(sp =>
{
    var opts = new HtmlSanitizerOptions();

    opts.AllowedTags.Remove("a");
    opts.AllowedAttributes.Remove("href");

    return new HtmlSanitizer(opts);
});
```

Comment: It will send out the empty list to the sanitizer. Please see my answer below to get the default list and then removing the tags explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I was answered [here](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer/discussions/391#discussioncomment-3598755)

Basically this code would work fine:

```
services.AddSingleton<Ganss.XSS.IHtmlSanitizer, Ganss.XSS.HtmlSanitizer>(m =>
{
    var options = new Ganss.XSS.HtmlSanitizerOptions
    {
        AllowedTags = Ganss.XSS.HtmlSanitizer.DefaultAllowedTags,
        AllowedAttributes = Gans.XSS.HtmlSanitizer.DefaultAllowedAttributes
    };

    options.AllowedTags.Remove("a");
    options.AllowedAttributes.Remove("href");

    var sanitizer = new Ganss.XSS.HtmlSanitizer(options);
    return sanitizer;
});
```